# $_GET Undefined Index (value from mysql table)

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Well i'm an absolute beginner considering PHP/HMTL programing and I'm stuck with these problem for days now.

First i've created Mysql table containing following columns (id, Name, Surname, Telephone_number, Email). Then I've successfully created form for reading table. Now i want to read and later edit a specific row using following code:

```
41 <?php
42 $con = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
43 mysql_select_db("database", $con);
44 $id=$_GET["id"];
45 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Table  where id='$id'");
46 $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
47 ?>
```

But all I get is the following error:
Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\contacts_edit.php on line 44

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Error says you that you must send id parameter with GET method from your html page

Comment: Have you called your script with something like `?id=123` at the end?

Comment: You are using [an obsolete database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and are exposing yourself to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/) that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: Have tried calling your script with an url like: `http://localhost/yourscript.php?id=';drop%20table%20Table;--1`?

Answer (score 6):

You haven't set the **GET** parameter in your URL. This is the reason why **id** is not defined in your global.

To prevent that problem check the variable before:

```
$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? (int)$_GET['id']: 0;
```

Or

```
if (!isset($_GET['id']) {
    $_GET['id'] = 0;
}
```

**A short hint for you...**

You should really look at SQL-Injections you have build a very big security hole.

Don't use **$_GET** and **$_POST** directly in your SQL query. You should prefer prepared statements with PDO or MySQLi. If you want to use your solution then cast your id to an integer value like this:

```
$id = (int)$_GET['id'];
```

then you have a default value 0 when its not set.

Comment: @user1758545 is your questions answered? Then you should mark one answer as correct.

Answer (score 2):

You have to check first that the id is set

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
mysql_select_db("database", $con);

if(isset($_GET['id'])) {

   $id=$_GET["id"];
   $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Table  where id='$id'");
   $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
}
?>
```

The better approach is to use pdo or mysqli.

[How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?lq=1)

Comment: I'd also escape the value. But this is will fix the issue.

Comment: This is vulnerable (like the code in the original question) to SQL injection and should not be used as is.

Comment: The id is not set. I want for program to automaticly detect id, depends which row i want to read/edit.

Answer (score 1):

I did this and worked for me

```
 <?php
 $con = mysql_connect("localhost","***","***");
 mysql_select_db("***", $con);
 if(isset($_GET["id"]) && !empty($_GET["id"])){
    $id= $_GET['id'];
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM core_usuarios  where id=".$id);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    print_r($row);
}
 ?>
```

By the way, if you want to connect to a database and you are using "plain php" it's better if you use PDO PHP http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php

Answer (score -1):

You should have something like this

```
http://site.com/contacts_edit.php?id=1
```

And in contacts_edit.php then you can use `$_GET['id']`

Bye

Comment: Changing the input to the program is not a solution, since the input is under the control of the user. The program needs to be robust enough to handle bad input.

Comment: Hi is not asking for best practices, he is asking about a specific error. Obviously he should protect his application, but we are not here answering that, otherwise, you should be writing that same tip on almost every single question here that uses $_POST and $_GET My answer tells how to use what he has

Answer (score -1):

You should do something like this :

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
mysql_select_db("database", $con);
if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
  $id=$_GET["id"];
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Table  where id='$id'");
  $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
}
```

Comment: This is a game of spot-the-difference, it doesn't explain anything, and is (like the code in the original question) vulnerable to SQL injection.